# Link to some action of a different CRUD controller

Tags: symfony, crud, easyadmin

Is there any workaround to link a new action, in a CRUD controller made with `EasyAdmin 4.x` , to an action in another CRUD controller with which it has a OneToMany relation ?

```
class FirstEntityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
...
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    return $actions
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::new('add-second-entity','Add a second entity')
        ->linkToCrudAction(Action::NEW ???)

            )
        ;
    }
}
```

[The docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html) say that I can use:

> linkToCrudAction(): to execute some method of the current CRUD controller;

But there seems to be no indication on how to "execute some method of **a different** CRUD controller".

Note:
There is a sneaky way around it but it doesn't seem healthy :

```
   ->linkToUrl('the url to the desired action')
```

Using:

- PHP 8.1
- Symfony 5.4
- EasyAdmin 4.x

Comment: I think you can try to use [UrlGenerator](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#generating-admin-urls) with `linkToUrl()`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following  *@Ruban*'s comment, and as [**EasyAdminBundle**'s docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#generating-crud-urls-from-outside-easyadmin) mention, we can generate a URL for the desired action using the `AdminUrlGenerator` class as follow:

```
class FirstEntityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    private $adminUrlGenerator;

    public function __construct(AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator)
    {
        $this->adminUrlGenerator = $adminUrlGenerator;
    }
    ...
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        //The magic happens here 
        $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SecondEntityCrudController::class)
            ->setAction(Action::NEW)
            ->generateUrl();

        return $actions
          //->... 
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 
                  Action::new('add-second-entity', 'Add second entity')
                ->linkToUrl($url)
            );
    }
}
```

This worked for me.